# Different indentation in files with same modes

Tags: c++

My `.cxx` files have 8-character indentation, while `.cpp` files have 4-character one. They have exact same modes enabled:

[image: cxx vs cpp]

My `auto-mode-alist` has the following c++ lines:

`("\\.ii\\'" . c++-mode)
 ("\\.h\\'" . c-or-c++-mode)
 ("\\.c\\'" . c-mode)
 ("\\.\\(CC?\\|HH?\\)\\'" . c++-mode)
 ("\\.[ch]\\(pp\\|xx\\|\\+\\+\\)\\'" . c++-mode)
 ("\\.\\(cc\\|hh\\)\\'" . c++-mode)`

How can I fix the `.cxx` files?

Comment: Are your `.cxx` files indented with tabs?

Comment: @nega within the buffer I move through indentation as spaces. I also tried setting `tab-width` to 4 and that did not change anything

Comment: The cc-modes (c++-mode, c-mode, java-mode, etc) won't auto-re-indent your files. So if there's already 8 spaces when you load it, that's what Emacs will show you.

Comment: @nega Excellent! I ran `M-x` + `indent-region` (`C-M-\ `), saved and now it opens properly. Also, when I copy new code into new `.cxx` file it opens with 4-character indentation. Could you please turn your comment into an answer for me to accept it? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out by [nega](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/12713/nega) in the comments, I should have re-indented the file after fixing offset in my `init.el` file:

```
(setq c-default-style "linux"
      c-basic-offset 4); <-- this changes the default value 8 to 4.
```